How would I calculate plasma density profile for a plasma in a magnetic field?
I want to find the density profile of a xenon gas plasma at a given pressure.
My current approach is to model the plasma as a fluid and use the continuity equation below:
$\frac{\partial n(\vec{r},t)}{\partial t} - D \nabla^2 n(\vec{r},t) = Q(\vec{r})$
Where $n$ is the electron/ion density, $D$ is the ambipolar diffusion coefficient, and $Q(\vec{r})$ is the ionization source
$Q(\vec{r})$ is intended to be a $\vec{B}$ field accelerating electrons until they ionize more atoms via collisions, but I'm stuck on how to model $Q(\vec{r})$ for this scenario.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
